# Windows Service with an IHostedService as a BackgroundService on .NET Core 7 not calling OnStop() method when shutdown

Tags: c#, windows, .net-core, service, .net-7.0

I have this service registered and starting up when the PC is turned on. The service is just monitoring a folder activity and it should write to a text file some data when the PC is being shutdown.

I am trying to do this when the `StopAsync` function gets fired, which is part of the BackgroundService implementation.

To simplify testing, I have just added a logging message that should appear in the windows events log next time I restart the PC. If I stop the service manually, this message appears correctly, and even when implementing the saving file task, that happens too.

But when I turn off the PC, once I start it again, all other messages are in the Windows Event log except the last one, the one from `StopAsync`.

My `StopAsync` function looks like this:

```
 public override Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
     logger.LogWarning("Test Service is Stopping...");
     return base.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
 }
```

I dont have the "Fast Startup" system configuration set.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into this issue for a long time, and finally having contact with the developers of .NET, turns out that in the case of a shutdown, the task `StopAsync` will fire but you cant be 100% sure that all the resources you need are still loaded. This includes the logging systems.

For more detailed information here is the link with the [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/83093).

This is relevant up to .NET Core 7.

Answer (score 0):

Try to override method `OnShutdown()` with the adjustment of `RequestAdditionalTime`.

```
protected override void OnShutdown()
{
    // Increase the service shutdown timeout to 60 seconds
    this.RequestAdditionalTime(60000);

    // Call the base method to handle the shutdown event
    base.OnShutdown();
}
```

I believe the problem can be that the operating system forcefully terminates your service before `StopAsync()` will be called.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But in .NET Core that override doesnt exist, because the BackgroundService class doesnt contain it. I believe this was the case for services before, but as I said, BackgroundService doesnt contain a definition for that function.